# Cropping a boundary box using webcam in yolov8 for confidence < 0.5

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection, webcam, yolov8

I am using a custom yolov8 object detection model with my webcam. I am able to make detections with the webcam but i am not able to get the saved cropped images from the video feed for detected confidence of less than 0.5. If I can get any help with this from the community or personally i would appreciate that. my code is as follows.

```
import cv2
import sys
import os
from ultralytics import YOLO
import time


model = YOLO("C:/Users/Graham/Documents/YoloRobo/runs/detect/train5/weights/best.pt")  # path to model file

results = model.predict(source="0", show=True,show_conf=True, line_width=2) 
time.sleep(2)

print(results)


for *xyxy, conf, cls in results.xyxy[0]:

    if conf < 0.5:
        image = results[0].path
        xyxy = results[0].boxes.xyxy.tolist()
        conf = results[0].boxes.conf.tolist()

        # Crop detected object
        crop_img = img.crop((xyxy[0], xyxy[1], xyxy[2], xyxy[3]))
        
        # Generate a file name based on the detected class and confidence
        object_name = model.names[int(cls)]
        cropped_file_name = f"{object_name}_{conf:.3f}.png"
        
        # Save the cropped image
        crop_img.save(cropped_file_name)
        print(f"Saved: {cropped_file_name}")

# Inform the user if no objects were found with confidence < 0.5
if len(results.xyxy[0]) == 0:
    print("No objects found with confidence less than 0.5.")

k=0
# Close the window when key q is pressed
while k!=113:
  # Display the image
  cv2.imshow("Window", image)
  k = cv2.waitKey(0)
 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code runs and I don't get the above error but when i end the code i also get the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 

 Cell In[2], line 16
    for *xyxy, conf, cls in results.xyxy[0]:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xyxy'
```

I have tried to update `OpenCV` and include the code for the specific bounding boxes along with altering the `xyxy` coordinates to try and call it but nothing has worked. I'm wondering if a delay to capture the crop image would also be useful, but it doesn't take the cropped bounding box with confidence less than 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the `results` object which is the response is of datatype **list**. Your code seems to be and output of the type GeneralizedYOLOv4, which is not equivalent to list. In the mentioned version you can directly call the xyxy as an attribute of the object and perform further actions.

You can check the same using `isinstance(results, yolov4.GeneralizedYOLOv4)`
If GeneralizedYOLOv4 object is not the response, it could be due to some issues witht the input or model not being loaded correctly, given this is an optional step to prove the context

Do refer to the latest [documentation](https://docs.ultralytics.com/) and check the corresponding example.

You can use the specified code inorder to retrive the boxes

```
results = model(img)
    for idx, result in enumerate(results):  
        boxes = result.boxes
```